# Where can I find the latest Swift documentation?

Tags: swift

I checked the latest version of official Swift Programming Language guide and it still uses the old style array String[] instead of [String].  On Apple's Swift blog, I see mention of access control (public, private, internal) and I am not seeing it in the documentation.

Where can I find the latest Swift documentation or get the most updated spec to the language?

Comment: Where did you find the version you read?

Comment: StackOverflow and blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the latest version of *The Swift Programming Language*, and it uses the new syntax, as expected. In the iBooks version, for example, on page 7:

> `let emptyArray = [String]()`
>
> `let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()`
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l

This is also reflected in [the web version](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1).

Access control is [detailed in a section toward the end of the Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29).

If you've found old syntax in the latest version, you should probably file a bug report. Where did you get your copy? If it's from iBooks, I've found that deleting your local copy and re-downloading can sometimes be needed to force an update.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, I looked at the iBooks version and it's still using the old syntax.  So maybe iBooks has the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through this..
https://www.topcoder.com/blog/how-i-started-learning-swift/
you'll find all the resources where you can get find swift resources.

The following is the link to Apple's swift ibook.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Apple Swift Developer Link. (Maybe of Use)
https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

Follow this link for more updates on swift.
https://www.topcoder.com/tag/swift/